# Quickly Evaluate Infix Math Expression?

Tags: calc, eval-expression, numbers

Is there a way to highlight and quickly evaluate a simple math expression without using elisp notation? For example, we can already evaluate the elisp expression `(+ 1 1)` in the following text snippet by putting point behind it and pressing <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>.

```
Here is a math equation: (+ 1 1)
```

But can we also do

```
Here is a math equation: 1 + 1
```

And get its result?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the built-in `calc` package to do so.

1. Mark your expression, e.g. `3 * (1 + 1)`
2. Call `calc-grab-region`

   - Call `calc-dispatch` (default `C-x *`), then hit `g`

Comment: You can also use `C-u C-x * e` while the expression is marked, and the marked expression will be replaced by the result. Afterwards, use `C-x * x` to exit calc.

Comment: I just tried this, and did not need to perform the second step `calc-dispatch g`.

Comment: I meant `calc-dispatch`, then `g` performs `calc-grab-region`.

Answer (score 3):

You might also use `calc`'s embedded mode if you intent to **replace** an expression with its result in the current buffer. <kbd>C-u C-x * e</kbd> when your formula / expression is on it's own on a separate line.

Otherwise mark it and type <kbd>C-0 C-x * e</kbd>

(Update: thanks to Dodgie, forgot to mention that) When you are finished with your mathematical manipulations type <kbd>C-x * e</kbd> again to end embedded `calc` mode.