# Call Python from YaSnippet and insert result

Tags: python, yasnippet

I'm trying to build a comparable functionality as described here:
https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/#sympy-and-mathematica

Basically, he's using something comparable to yasnippet to send a dedicated region to yasnippet and sends it to python, printing it's return value.

I don't even know how to call python and just return it to the buffer in the first place, neither how to let yasnippet do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That demo is quite formidable — thanks for bringing it to our attention!! I suggest you open a "bug-report" on yasnippet asking whether it can/cannot be done in yasnippet. If yes pointers please. If no may I (you) make a feature request. You should of course do some legwork such as how the sympy call would work from elisp at the least -- maybe synchronously, but also possibly async https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Subprocess-Creation.html#Subprocess-Creation

Comment: I do see that elisp can be called within backquotes. See https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#orgcde188c

Comment: A similar work with the linked one is started here: https://github.com/tecosaur/LaTeX-auto-activating-snippets.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options I found, none of which completely address this issue.

### 1. Evaluating Python directly in the buffer

Python can be evaluated in the buffer with the function "eval-region-as-py" from [Emacs SE - How to evaluate the selection through Python and replace the selection with it's result?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37029/how-to-evaluate-the-selection-through-python-and-replace-the-selection-with-its/37030). This returns the result in the buffer.

For example, let's evaluate this:

```
print("hello world!")
```

Running eval-region-as-py on this produces the following output.

```
hello world!
None
```

Then you can call this function in a yasnippet template to run it. Something like

```
`(eval-region-as-py yas-selected-text)`
```

should work.

You can suppress the "None" with another function. It's pretty involved, so I won't get into that here. (Maybe you can start researching it with [SO - Redirecting the output of a python function from STDOUT to variable in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250050/redirecting-the-output-of-a-python-function-from-stdout-to-variable-in-python) .)
I'm not sure how running sympy would work. When I tried it in my Emacs session, Sympy hangs while looking for definitions for each variable (e.g., `sin(x)` hangs because I didn't run `x = syms('x')` first.) using this implementation: [Emacs SE - How to evaluate the selection through Python and replace the selection with it's result?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37029/how-to-evaluate-the-selection-through-python-and-replace-the-selection-with-its/37030).
Normally, you would need to run `syms()` to define all the variables, but we don't know which variables we're using before trying to evaluate the expression.

---

### 2. Using org-mode instead of LaTeX (not really a way to resolve this problem)

Another option you could try is using org-mode (although this doesn't really answer your original question).

In org-mode, you can call something like

```
#+begin_src python :results output
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
print(sp.expand_trig(sp.sin(2*x) + sp.cos(2*x)))
#+end_src
```

which will result in the following.

```
#+RESULTS:
: 2*sin(x)*cos(x) + 2*cos(x)**2 - 1
```

---

## 3. Emacs Calc Embedded Mode

You type a command directly in your buffer. Suppose you typed in

```
solve(x^2 + 2*x - 1 = 0, x)
```

and evaluate it using `C-x * e`. This particular expression evaluates to

```
x = 0.414213562373
```

I got this idea from [Emacs SE - Quickly Evaluate Infix Math Expression?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38425/quickly-evaluate-infix-math-expression)

---

### 4. emaxima

You can try using emaxima ([TeX SE - emaxima on beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356744/emaxima-on-beamer)). Again, it won't give you the ability to run SymPy, but it will let you symbolically manipulate expressions and dump the results of that computation directly in the buffer.

---

### 5. Sage

You can use `sage-shell-mode` to evaluate things in the buffer. It doesn't dump the results directly in the buffer, though; you would need to write a wrapper function to do that. It also may run more slowly than the other options, depending on the Python implementation you're using.

Comment: The links in the answer seem to be mixed.

Comment: Regarding the org-mode solution, you can also name a source block and use `call_<name>(<arguments>)` to get the result of the source block. This allows the result to be in the middle of a sentence. See [the documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html) for more.

Comment: Unmixed the links. I didn't know about `call_name(arguments)`, thanks for the info! Another possible org-mode solution could be `src_<language>[<header arguments>]{<body>}` from [another page in the documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-of-Code-Blocks.html#Structure-of-Code-Blocks).